# All installations extremely slow- 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation

I had to re-install a fresh 14.04 LTS version.

First of all, it took me a whole night(or nearby) to install it.

Every installation of package (via ubuntu library or via sudo apt-get update ... sudo apt-get install - for example sudo apt-get install freefilesync) take ages.

I'm runnig a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Any Idea

Comment: I've double-check ed my internet connexion that can go up to 2.9 Mo/s descending. I precise that the problem occurs  for English (mainly used) or French packages liky the Google Chome package.

Comment: After further investigation it  seems thnat accesses to fr.archive.ubuntu.com are very slow. Could anybody  help on this problem ?

Comment: Example : Les NOUVEAUX paquets suivants seront installés :
  indicator-cpufreq libcpufreq0
0 mis à jour, 2 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 247 non mis à jour.
Il est nécessaire de prendre 47,4 ko dans les archives.
Après cette opération, 676 ko d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer ? [O/n] O
0% [Connexion à fr.archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1360:8c01::18)]
and stand stuck for ages

Comment: An other example where installation gets stuck : just after a sudo apt-get update  I get this "100% [Connexion à fr.archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1360:8c01::19)] [Connexion" and it stands stuck for minimum 10 mn

Comment: Try changing your mirror, http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt should give you a list of mirrors close to you (using geoip).

Comment: There is a gui method of pinging all servers and selecting the fastest to you, this is not always necessarily the closest.to you. If the problem is definitely slow server connection I could write this up formally as an answer?

Comment: Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good chance that you have selected an Ubuntu Repository mirror that is giving poor performance. You can ping all of the available servers and then select the best performing one by:

1. Opening 'Software & Updates
2. Selecting the tab 'Ubuntu'
3. Selecting 'Other...' from the 'Download From...' dropdown box
4. Selecting 'Select Best Server' from the 'Choose a Download Server' box

Below is a screen capture demonstrating these steps:

[image]

Then you need to:

5. Select the best server with 'Choose Server'
6. Authenticate with your password and reload the sources list when prompted

Bear in mind that this will not necessarily be the closest server to you geographically, the fastest server *at that time* will be selected. Depending on network load, time of day etc this server may not always be the best...

**References:**

- [Ubuntu Repositories: Download Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Download_Server)

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew. It works perfectly now even I do not understand that the best servers are in Switzerland as I am in France. Many thanks again.

Comment: Just one problem more : 100% [Connexion à archive.canonical.com (2001:67c:1360:8c01::1b)] [Connexion  takes ages to connect

Comment: Hmmm.... not sure about that, but bear in mind that there may be not much of use for you in thes canonical repositories...