# apt-get install extremely slow on Ubuntu 14.04 dual boot

Tags: 14.04, wireless, internet

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 64bits in dual boot with my Windows 10 and now when I want to install all necessary components I realize the (wireless) internet connection is very slow in Linux, being fast in Windows.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Is the answer to this question any help: http://askubuntu.com/q/729981/57576 ?

Comment: no I already set it to find the best server. No change