# Can't Install Unity 8 (Stuck on 'Waiting for headers') Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, unity8

I recently wanted to give unity 8 a shot so I entered this command into my terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install unity8-desktop-session-mir
```

But this is what happens:
[image]

I am using the Australian internode servers but even main servers don't help, its just stuck! Same goes for synaptic.

Can someone please help?

Comment: I am also in Australia and download of the same was very fast. Have a look here: http://askubuntu.com/a/735312/57576 and see if this makes a difference...