# Installing updates takes forever?

Tags: updates

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. When try to install updates, it takes forever. Its stuck in the below screen[image]

I tried restarting the system too. But it just stays there.

Comment: Run `sudo apt upgrade` and you will see the problem.

Comment: Perhaps try this solution: http://askubuntu.com/a/735312/57576

Answer (score 1):

It is due to IPv6.

Try doing this:
vim /etc/gai.conf

uncomment the line:
precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100

Save and exit.

Create the file:
sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4

And add the line:
Aquire::ForceIPv4 false;

Hope it helps!